# Adding label for last point of line in R plot

Tags: r, plot, label

Consider the following plot:

```
 par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
 q1 <- c(1000000.0,  908364.8,  876009.1,  847892.8,  824808.3,  805416.2,  785266.2, 770997.1,  753908.6,  744599.9,  706777.6,  674659.9,  634654.4,  601440.4, 568259.7,  535361.3,  493679.9,  465526.5,  429766.6,  395244.7,  361483.2, 332136.6, 308574.5, 285500.6, 262166.2 ,237989.0 , 210766.1,  188578.1, 166762.3 , 140399.8  ,114865.5)
 plot(q1, type = "l", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = "darkolivegreen3", ylim = c(0,4*10^6), xlim = c(1,30), bty = "l")
 text(30, q1[30], labels = "text", col = "gray36", cex = 0.8, pos = 4)
```

[image]

I would like to add the label "text" at the right of the last point of the green line (i.e. the point on the line with x = 30).

I tried the code above but the text doesn't show up! Any ideas how to solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: It's getting put below your plot. Try `pos=2`

Comment: `pos = 2` puts the label to the left of the point. I want to show it to the right of the point..

Comment: Then why would you have `x=30`?? That's the far right edge of your plot.

Comment: I apologize, I think I haven't been very clear in the post. I would like the label to appear on the margin of the plot, next to the line, in the white section right of the line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

By default things in a plot are clipped to the plot region, you are not seeing the text because it has been clipped.  You can either use the `mtext` function to explicitly place the text into the margin.  Or if you specify `par(xpd=NA)` then the clipping will be turned off (well it will still clip to the device region) and the text plotted using the `text` function will now be plotted extending into the margin.  Either way you will probably want to specify some space in the appropriate margin so there is room for the text to be and look nice.  See `?par` for how to specify the margin and more detail on clipping.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this could be done using `mtext`:

```
 mtext("text", side = 4, at = q1[30], las = 1)
```